# C# VisualStateManager - What is the equivalent in WPF for SelectedPointerOver (in Metro)

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro, visualstatemanager

I am creating a custom controltemplate for ListBox and I'm having difficulties with the visual states. When using the VisualState MouseOver, it affects all the items including the selected item, which I want to have separate styling.

In Metro, there is SelectedPointerOver, is there anything equivalent in WPF or other alternatives?

**Edit:**

For example, all items initially have black foreground.

When one item is selected, its foreground turns white (and non-selected items remain black foreground).

And now when I MouseOver the non-selected item, I will like its foreground to turn blue, and when I MouseOver the selected item, I will like its foreground to turn red.

Comment: For which control you want the SelectedPointerOver State... Do you mean any property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no equivalent to that state in WPF.

The WPF ListBoxItem has the states `Unselected`, `Selected` and `SelectedUnfocused` in group `SelectionStates` and the states `Normal`, `MouseOver` and `Disabled` in group `CommonStates`. States in each group are mutually exclusive, but states from different groups can be taken on simultaneously. The ListBoxItem can for example be in states `Selected` and `MouseOver` at the same time.

It is up to the control template to define a visualization that takes this fact into account. It could for example fill the item with a different background brush when it is selected, and draw an outer border when the mouse is over the item. The important thing is that there are independent visualizations that are *visible at the same time*, as the related states are independent and can be taken on at the same time. A user would typically become a bit confused when a selected list item doesn't look selected only because he moved the mouse over that item.

EDIT - ListBox example below. Could perhaps be done a lot easier with Triggers instead of Visual States.

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid Background="LightGray" Margin="1">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="UnselectedText"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                            To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedText"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                            To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="UnselectedText"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedText"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <TextBlock Name="UnselectedText" Margin="2" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                                </TextBlock.Foreground>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="SelectedText" Margin="2" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Opacity="0">
                                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                </TextBlock.Foreground>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 4"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 5"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 6"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 7"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 8"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 9"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 10"/>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm actually more interested to know if it will be possible to allow variation of visualizations based on the IsSelected property

Comment: That's exactly what the visual states `Selected` and `Unselected` were made for. See [ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242(v=vs.100)) for an example ControlTemplate that handles these states.

Comment: Let me clarify myself. I will like the selected item and non-selected item to change its style differently even when MouseOver happens. For example, all items initially have black foreground. When one item is selected, its foreground turns white. And now when I MouseOver the non-selected item, I will like its foreground to turn blue, and when I MouseOver the selected item, I will like its foreground to turn red. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: See the edit for a quick shot example of what you want to do. It is however somewhat ugly since it has two TextBlocks on top of each other, showing the same text with only different colors.